# Turn a specific block of text and generate rows in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to figure this out in JS/jQuery but can't wrap my head around it. I have a block of text that I want to paste into a textarea and it will generate x number of (table)rows with inputs from it. It is always a timecode followed by a text, followed by another timecode. How can I paste something like this into a textarea:

```
01:00:17:02.28  1m01 Main Title  00:02:32:17.47
01:22:04:15.77  Hit at 1:22:30   00:00:20:10.01
01:26:23:17.60  1M2s - End Title     00:01:22:14.01
```

And generate this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="01:00:17:02.28"></td>
        <td><input value="1"></td>
        <td><input value="m"></td>
        <td><input value="01"></td>
        <td><input value="Main Title"></td>
        <td><input value="00:02:32:17.47"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="01:22:04:15.77"></td>
        <td><input value=""></td>
        <td><input value=""></td>
        <td><input value=""></td>
        <td><input value="Hit at 1:22:30"></td>
        <td><input value="00:00:20:10.01"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="01:26:23:17.60"></td>
        <td><input value="101"></td>
        <td><input value="M"></td>
        <td><input value="2s"></td>
        <td><input value="End Title"></td>
        <td><input value="00:01:22:14.01"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In other words:

1. Break out the first timecode
2. Look if the middle block starts with the syntax 1m1s (digits, upper or lowercase "m", string... no spaces). If yes, separate those
   three out and if there is anything else after that put it in it's
   own input.
3. If the middle block didn't start with the syntax, put the whole
   string in the 5th input
4. End with the last timecode

A bonus is if the 5th input can trim off any separators. Like "- End Title" would be "End Title" in the third row.

Thankful for ideas!

Comment: You'll need to take a stab at it and ask a specific question if you get stuck. Tools will be regular expressions (primarily), `split` on strings (to break it into lines), probably `forEach` or `map` on arrays, and of course generating the elements either via `createElement` or by generating markup and using jQuery's `html` on an existing element to fill it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can work with, the rest should be pretty straight forward. There are many different functions in Javascript that you can use to query and manipulate strings, I used different ones so you could use it for future reference.

```
01:00:17:02.28  1m01 Main Title  00:02:32:17.47
01:22:04:15.77  Hit at 1:22:30   00:00:20:10.01
01:26:23:17.60  1M2s - End Title     00:01:22:14.01
```

If you copy the above, and paste it in the textfield, then click the button, it should sort the string according to your conditions.

```js
function niceFunction() {
  var test = document.getElementById("test").value;
  var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
  var awesomeObjects = doCoolThingsWithString(test);
  for(var x = 0; x<=2; x++){
   div1.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML + " | first segment = " +awesomeObjects[x].first;
    div1.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML + " | second segment = " + awesomeObjects[x].second;
    
    if(awesomeObjects[x].fourth){
     div1.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML + " | third segment = " +awesomeObjects[x].third;
     div1.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML + " | fourth segment = " +awesomeObjects[x].fourth + "</br>";
    }
    else{
     div1.innerHTML = div1.innerHTML + " | third segment = " +awesomeObjects[x].third+ "</br>";
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = niceFunction;
function doCoolThingsWithString(string) {
  var test = string;
  var doubleSplit = [];
  test = test.replace(/\n\r?/g, '|');
  test = test.replace('-','');
  test = test.split("|");
  //test = test.match(/\S+/g);

  for (var x = 0; x <= test.length - 1; x++) {
    var temp = test[x].match(/\S+/g);
    if (isNaN(parseInt(temp[1].substring(0, 1)))) {
      var second = temp[1] + " " + temp[2] + " " + temp[3];
      doubleSplit.push({
        "first": temp[0],
        "second": second,
        "third": temp[4],
        "bool": isNaN(parseInt(temp[1].substring(0, 1)))
      });
    } else {
      var third = temp[2] + " " + temp[3];
      doubleSplit.push({
        "first": temp[0],
        "second": temp[1],
        "third": third,
        "fourth": temp[4],
        "bool": isNaN(parseInt(temp[1].substring(0, 1)))
      });
    }
  }
  //test = test[5];
  return doubleSplit;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="test">
</textarea>
<div id="div1"></div>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" />
```

Some explanation:

- get the textbox value
- replace line break with an obvious character, in my case `|` (`replace` function)
- remove the `-` according to your requirements (`replace` function)
- split the string by `|` character (`split` function)
- split functions creates an array, index 0 for example would be `01:00:17:02.28  1m01 Main Title  00:02:32:17.47`...
- loop over the array and use `match` function to get all non-whitespace (stored as an array)
- check if the first character of the second index is `NaN` (not a number)
- if it is not a number then implement one requirement
- else implement the other requirement
- store it in a list of dictionaries for easier access
- create your tags using `createElement` function like so `var x = document.createElement("TABLE");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435067/js-regexp-for-specific-pattern