# JS/Regexp for specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get /^1m1/.test(text) to look if the strong starts with the following pattern: "digits, m|M, str".

A few examples that I want to return true if the string starts with it: "1m1", "1m01 Text", "101M01s Other Text", "1m002 Text", "2M15B Another Text".

A few examples that should return false:
"10 Text", "1m Other Text", "Text 1m1", "Just Some Text", "101 1m1"

Maybe it can be split Into two variables? So "1m1" would fill var1 only, "101m2abc Text any length" would fill var1(101m2abc) and var2(Text any length) and "Text any length" would only fill var2.

Comment: Your test cases are a little bit unclear due to the inline formatting. Could you please edit and place them on separate lines, or denote strings with `"Text"`?

Comment: are you sure "101M01s Other Text" comes up in accepted test case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that any character other than a white space can follow `m` then my regex would be `/^\d+m\S\.*/i`. Accordingly;

```js
console.log(["10 Text", "1m Other Text", "Text 1m1", "Just Some Text", "101 1m1"].some(s => (/^\d+m\S\.*/i.test(s))));

console.log(["1m1", "1m01 Text", "101M01s Other Text", "1m002 Text", "2M15B Another Text"].every(s => (/^\d+m\S\.*/i.test(s))));
```

Comment: Amazing! Works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hers's how you can do it :

> `^`  : anchor to start of the text
>
> `[0-9]`  OR `\d{1}` : accepts any digit from 0-9 (Tip: if you'd like to not match to '9' you can use `[0-8]`)
>
> `(m|M)`: matches to 'm' or 'M' (Tip: I would prefer using case insensitive matching here, you can use `i` flag for same)

To sum it all up

```
/^\d{1}m./i.test(str)
```

(I've used case-insensitive matching here)

```js
var array = ["1m1", "1m01 Text", "101M01s Other Text", "1m002 Text", "2M15B Another Text", "10 Text", "1m Other Text", "Text 1m1", "Just Some Text", "101 1m1"]

var passedArray = [];

array.forEach(function(str){
  if(/^\d{1}m./i.test(str)){
    passedArray.push(str);
  }
});

console.log('passedArray :', passedArray);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is \d working for non singles as well? E.g. 101m120abc?

Comment: @SeaBass, yes it does, I've updated my answer to limit it to one occurrence. I'm not sure what you meant by spliting it into variables but I've updated my answer to collect all passed cases in an array

Answer (score 1):

You could look for some numbers, an `m`, case does not matter, again some numbers and optional for some non numbers.

```js
var strings = ['1m1', '1m01 Text', '101M01s Other Text', '1m002 Text', '2M15B Another Text', '10 Text', '1m Other Text', 'Text 1m1', 'Just Some Text', '101 1m1'];

strings.map(s => console.log(/^\d+m\d+\D*$/i.test(s), s));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I just updated my post to be clearer and to see if I can get it separated into one or two variables.